# Capturing step by step actions

Tags: screenshot

Is there some tool to automated capture of step by step actions and screenshots during some task performing on computer with Ubuntu?

P.S. Just for illustration, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224213141/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/patricka/archive/2010/01/04/using-the-secret-windows-7-problem-step-recorder-to-create-step-by-step-screenshot-documents.aspx) is one software to capture step by step actions to Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Wink to record your screen actions.

> Wink is a Tutorial and Presentation creation software, primarily aimed
>   at creating tutorials on how to use software (like a tutor for
>   MS-Word/Excel etc). Using Wink you can capture screenshots, add
>   explanations boxes, buttons, titles etc and generate a highly
>   effective tutorial for your users.

To download and install visit the [website](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/download.htm).

<sup>Source:Wink</sup>

Comment: Tks Mitch. When I tried to install it, I got the error: missing libexpat.so.0. Do you have any suggestion to solve it? Cheers.

Comment: Try this: run `sudo apt-cache search libexpat`, and then `sudo apt-get install libexpat1`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I did what you said, but the same message appears. :(